# On Azure DevOps Boards how to create new item and automatically load a template (not selecting it)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

When on Azure DevOps when creating a new Board item the new item is empty then I can go to the top right and select a template.

What I want is to do that automatically. I want for a template to be loaded into the newly created item without me going directly to the template option on the top right. I want the template to be present right after pressing the New item button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to copy the template link and put it in the dashboard, then, click on the link will open a new work item with the template.

1) Open settings for a team.

2) Expand **Boards** and choose **Team Configuration**. Then, choose **Templates**.

3) Copy the template link.

4) Go to the Dashboard, add a Markdown widget and paste the link.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Inside a work item when you select  Actions-->Template-->Capture (just to pick up a properly done template) I can not edit/delete templates that have been done this way.

Comment: Also notice that when created the way you mention after a while the template dissapears :S

Comment: To mention they dissapear from the Template Configuration but still accessible through the URL.